# equivalent for "ismember" of matlab in opencv?

Tags: c++, c, matlab, opencv, code-conversion

What is the equivalent of "ismember" of matlab in opencv?

I am trying to convert a matlab code to opencv ( C/CPP ). For this I need to convert the below step to Opencv. Can some one please guide me in this regard?

```
[Lia Locb1] = ismember(tl(:,1),ind3);

  where Mat tl = Mat::ones(106, 3, CV_8U); and
        ind3 = find(Sm(:,1) >= xm & Sm(:,1) <= xM & Sm(:,2) >= ym & Sm(:,2) <= yM);
```

Comment: If you explain what it does in words, you may summon the help of those who know C++ but not matlab.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really equivalent, but if a is a scalar `ismember(a,b)` can be replaced by `any(a==b)`.

Not sure if this helps you in OpenCv, otherwise you can ofcourse always replace ismember by a simple loop to check equality of `a` with all elements in `b`.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a one liner??? a is not a scalar...it is a column matrix....